# pandas groupby not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, fillna

I have a dataframe:

```
    >>> d6
Out[57]: 
            Date      sym   Last    M1      M2         dist           code
52735 2017-11-23       C    0.10   4.72   -9.27       677.93  4250 - 12/15/2017
52736 2017-11-23       P  684.20   1.43 -106.09       677.93  4250 - 12/15/2017
53144 2017-11-23       C    0.10   4.49   -9.37       727.93  4300 - 12/15/2017
53145 2017-11-23       P  734.20   0.69 -105.02       727.93  4300 - 12/15/2017
52738 2017-11-23       P  784.20    nan     nan       777.93  4350 - 12/15/2017
52737 2017-11-23       C    0.10   4.29   -9.46       777.93  4350 - 12/15/2017
53081 2017-11-23       P  834.20    nan     nan       827.93  4400 - 12/15/2017
53019 2017-11-23       C    0.10   4.12   -9.55       827.93  4400 - 12/15/2017
52747 2017-11-23       C    0.10   3.96   -9.64       877.93  4450 - 12/15/2017
52748 2017-11-23       P  884.20    nan     nan       877.93  4450 - 12/15/2017
52605 2017-11-23       C    0.10   3.81   -9.71       927.93  4500 - 12/15/2017
52606 2017-11-23       P  934.20    nan     nan       927.93  4500 - 12/15/2017
52753 2017-11-23       C    0.10   3.68   -9.79       977.93  4550 - 12/15/2017
52754 2017-11-23       P  984.30   2.04 -109.96       977.93  4550 - 12/15/2017
53020 2017-11-23       C    0.10   3.56   -9.86      1027.93  4600 - 12/15/2017
53082 2017-11-23       P 1034.30   1.55 -108.99      1027.93  4600 - 12/15/2017
54698 2017-11-23       P 1134.30   0.53 -106.79      1127.93  4700 - 12/15/2017
54687 2017-11-23       C    0.10   3.35   -9.99      1127.93  4700 - 12/15/2017
52337 2017-11-23       C    0.10   3.17  -10.11      1227.93  4800 - 12/15/2017
52338 2017-11-23       P 1234.30    nan     nan      1227.93  4800 - 12/15/2017
54699 2017-11-23       P 1334.30    nan     nan      1327.93  4900 - 12/15/2017
54688 2017-11-23       C    0.10   3.01  -10.22      1327.93  4900 - 12/15/2017
52191 2017-11-23       P    0.10   0.55  -11.15     -3072.07   500 - 12/15/2017
52190 2017-11-23       C 3066.80   0.29   82.60     -3072.07   500 - 12/15/2017
52339 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.87  -10.32      1427.93  5000 - 12/15/2017
52340 2017-11-23       P 1434.40   1.26 -110.86      1427.93  5000 - 12/15/2017
54689 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.75  -10.41      1527.93  5100 - 12/15/2017
54700 2017-11-23       P 1534.40   0.45 -108.55      1527.93  5100 - 12/15/2017
52341 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.65  -10.50      1627.93  5200 - 12/15/2017
52342 2017-11-23       P 1634.40    nan     nan      1627.93  5200 - 12/15/2017
52439 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.55  -10.58      1727.93  5300 - 12/15/2017
52440 2017-11-23       P 1734.50   1.72 -114.79      1727.93  5300 - 12/15/2017
52343 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.46  -10.66      1827.93  5400 - 12/15/2017
52344 2017-11-23       P 1834.50   1.08 -112.69      1827.93  5400 - 12/15/2017
54701 2017-11-23       P 1934.50   0.40 -110.30      1927.93  5500 - 12/15/2017
54690 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.38  -10.73      1927.93  5500 - 12/15/2017
52346 2017-11-23       P 2034.50    nan     nan      2027.93  5600 - 12/15/2017
52345 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.31  -10.80      2027.93  5600 - 12/15/2017
54691 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.24  -10.87      2127.93  5700 - 12/15/2017
54702 2017-11-23       P 2134.60   1.52 -116.68      2127.93  5700 - 12/15/2017
52348 2017-11-23       P 2234.60   0.97 -114.51      2227.93  5800 - 12/15/2017
52347 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.18  -10.93      2227.93  5800 - 12/15/2017
54703 2017-11-23       P 2334.60   0.37 -112.06      2327.93  5900 - 12/15/2017
54692 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.13  -10.99      2327.93  5900 - 12/15/2017
52192 2017-11-23       C 2966.80   0.46   80.38     -2972.07   600 - 12/15/2017
52193 2017-11-23       P    0.10   0.61  -11.16     -2972.07   600 - 12/15/2017
52349 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.08  -11.05      2427.93  6000 - 12/15/2017
52350 2017-11-23       P 2434.60    nan     nan      2427.93  6000 - 12/15/2017
52194 2017-11-23       C 2866.70    nan     nan     -2872.07   700 - 12/15/2017
52195 2017-11-23       P    0.10   0.67  -11.16     -2872.07   700 - 12/15/2017
54449 2017-11-23       C    0.10   1.71  -11.52      3427.93  7000 - 12/15/2017
54479 2017-11-23       P 3434.90   0.77 -119.84      3427.93  7000 - 12/15/2017
57740 2017-11-24       C  787.75    nan     nan      -781.23  2800 - 11/24/2017
57742 2017-11-24       P    0.01    nan     nan      -781.23  2800 - 11/24/2017
57741 2017-11-24       C  737.75    nan     nan      -731.23  2850 - 11/24/2017
57743 2017-11-24       P    0.01    nan     nan      -731.23  2850 - 11/24/2017
57730 2017-11-24       C  687.75    nan     nan      -681.23  2900 - 11/24/2017
57735 2017-11-24       P    0.01    nan     nan      -681.23  2900 - 11/24/2017
57731 2017-11-24       C  637.75    nan     nan      -631.23  2950 - 11/24/2017
57736 2017-11-24       P    0.01    nan     nan      -631.23  2950 - 11/24/2017
57732 2017-11-24       C  587.75    nan     nan      -581.23  3000 - 11/24/2017
57737 2017-11-24       P    0.01    nan     nan      -581.23  3000 - 11/24/2017
57733 2017-11-24       C  537.75    nan     nan      -531.23  3050 - 11/24/2017
57738 2017-11-24       P    0.01    nan     nan      -531.23  3050 - 11/24/2017
57727 2017-11-24       P    0.20   7.77  -25.05      -431.23  3150 - 12/08/2017
57728 2017-11-24       P    0.30  11.49  -34.45      -381.23  3200 - 12/08/2017
57734 2017-11-24       C  362.75    nan     nan      -356.23  3225 - 11/24/2017
57739 2017-11-24       P    0.01    nan     nan      -356.23  3225 - 11/24/2017
57729 2017-11-24       P    0.40  14.84  -43.17      -356.23  3225 - 12/08/2017
57826 2017-11-24       C  234.50 140.14 -124.53      -231.23  3350 - 12/22/2017
57845 2017-11-24       P    5.70 140.19 -156.23      -231.23  3350 - 12/22/2017
57827 2017-11-24       C  210.50 160.38 -138.61      -206.23  3375 - 12/22/2017
57846 2017-11-24       P    6.70 160.34 -170.27      -206.23  3375 - 12/22/2017
```

Although I have shown only 2 dates above, it has a lot of dates. Each date has an entry for a few "codes". Each code on a given date has 2 entries - one for sympbol C and one for P. If I have M1/M2 entries for either C or P, i want to fill the "nan" with that for that code/day. If both C and P are nan for a given code+day, I leave it nan.

I am currently doing it as follows:

```
for code in d1.code:
        x_df = d1[d1.code == code]
        x_df = x_df.groupby(['Date'], as_index=False).ffill().bfill()
        d1[d1.code == code] = x_df
```

This works but takes a long time. Here is the output for the df above:

```
Out[62]: 
            Date      sym   Last    M1      M2         dist           code
52735 2017-11-23       C    0.10   4.72   -9.27       677.93  4250 - 12/15/2017
52736 2017-11-23       P  684.20   1.43 -106.09       677.93  4250 - 12/15/2017
53144 2017-11-23       C    0.10   4.49   -9.37       727.93  4300 - 12/15/2017
53145 2017-11-23       P  734.20   0.69 -105.02       727.93  4300 - 12/15/2017
52738 2017-11-23       P  784.20   4.29   -9.46       777.93  4350 - 12/15/2017
52737 2017-11-23       C    0.10   4.29   -9.46       777.93  4350 - 12/15/2017
53081 2017-11-23       P  834.20   4.12   -9.55       827.93  4400 - 12/15/2017
53019 2017-11-23       C    0.10   4.12   -9.55       827.93  4400 - 12/15/2017
52747 2017-11-23       C    0.10   3.96   -9.64       877.93  4450 - 12/15/2017
52748 2017-11-23       P  884.20   3.96   -9.64       877.93  4450 - 12/15/2017
52605 2017-11-23       C    0.10   3.81   -9.71       927.93  4500 - 12/15/2017
52606 2017-11-23       P  934.20   3.81   -9.71       927.93  4500 - 12/15/2017
52753 2017-11-23       C    0.10   3.68   -9.79       977.93  4550 - 12/15/2017
52754 2017-11-23       P  984.30   2.04 -109.96       977.93  4550 - 12/15/2017
53020 2017-11-23       C    0.10   3.56   -9.86      1027.93  4600 - 12/15/2017
53082 2017-11-23       P 1034.30   1.55 -108.99      1027.93  4600 - 12/15/2017
54698 2017-11-23       P 1134.30   0.53 -106.79      1127.93  4700 - 12/15/2017
54687 2017-11-23       C    0.10   3.35   -9.99      1127.93  4700 - 12/15/2017
52337 2017-11-23       C    0.10   3.17  -10.11      1227.93  4800 - 12/15/2017
52338 2017-11-23       P 1234.30   3.17  -10.11      1227.93  4800 - 12/15/2017
54699 2017-11-23       P 1334.30   3.01  -10.22      1327.93  4900 - 12/15/2017
54688 2017-11-23       C    0.10   3.01  -10.22      1327.93  4900 - 12/15/2017
52191 2017-11-23       P    0.10   0.55  -11.15     -3072.07   500 - 12/15/2017
52190 2017-11-23       C 3066.80   0.29   82.60     -3072.07   500 - 12/15/2017
52339 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.87  -10.32      1427.93  5000 - 12/15/2017
52340 2017-11-23       P 1434.40   1.26 -110.86      1427.93  5000 - 12/15/2017
54689 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.75  -10.41      1527.93  5100 - 12/15/2017
54700 2017-11-23       P 1534.40   0.45 -108.55      1527.93  5100 - 12/15/2017
52341 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.65  -10.50      1627.93  5200 - 12/15/2017
52342 2017-11-23       P 1634.40   2.65  -10.50      1627.93  5200 - 12/15/2017
52439 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.55  -10.58      1727.93  5300 - 12/15/2017
52440 2017-11-23       P 1734.50   1.72 -114.79      1727.93  5300 - 12/15/2017
52343 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.46  -10.66      1827.93  5400 - 12/15/2017
52344 2017-11-23       P 1834.50   1.08 -112.69      1827.93  5400 - 12/15/2017
54701 2017-11-23       P 1934.50   0.40 -110.30      1927.93  5500 - 12/15/2017
54690 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.38  -10.73      1927.93  5500 - 12/15/2017
52346 2017-11-23       P 2034.50   2.31  -10.80      2027.93  5600 - 12/15/2017
52345 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.31  -10.80      2027.93  5600 - 12/15/2017
54691 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.24  -10.87      2127.93  5700 - 12/15/2017
54702 2017-11-23       P 2134.60   1.52 -116.68      2127.93  5700 - 12/15/2017
52348 2017-11-23       P 2234.60   0.97 -114.51      2227.93  5800 - 12/15/2017
52347 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.18  -10.93      2227.93  5800 - 12/15/2017
54703 2017-11-23       P 2334.60   0.37 -112.06      2327.93  5900 - 12/15/2017
54692 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.13  -10.99      2327.93  5900 - 12/15/2017
52192 2017-11-23       C 2966.80   0.46   80.38     -2972.07   600 - 12/15/2017
52193 2017-11-23       P    0.10   0.61  -11.16     -2972.07   600 - 12/15/2017
52349 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.08  -11.05      2427.93  6000 - 12/15/2017
52350 2017-11-23       P 2434.60   2.08  -11.05      2427.93  6000 - 12/15/2017
52194 2017-11-23       C 2866.70   0.67  -11.16     -2872.07   700 - 12/15/2017
52195 2017-11-23       P    0.10   0.67  -11.16     -2872.07   700 - 12/15/2017
54449 2017-11-23       C    0.10   1.71  -11.52      3427.93  7000 - 12/15/2017
54479 2017-11-23       P 3434.90   0.77 -119.84      3427.93  7000 - 12/15/2017
57740 2017-11-24       C  787.75    nan     nan      -781.23  2800 - 11/24/2017
57742 2017-11-24       P    0.01    nan     nan      -781.23  2800 - 11/24/2017
57741 2017-11-24       C  737.75    nan     nan      -731.23  2850 - 11/24/2017
57743 2017-11-24       P    0.01    nan     nan      -731.23  2850 - 11/24/2017
57730 2017-11-24       C  687.75    nan     nan      -681.23  2900 - 11/24/2017
57735 2017-11-24       P    0.01    nan     nan      -681.23  2900 - 11/24/2017
57731 2017-11-24       C  637.75    nan     nan      -631.23  2950 - 11/24/2017
57736 2017-11-24       P    0.01    nan     nan      -631.23  2950 - 11/24/2017
57732 2017-11-24       C  587.75    nan     nan      -581.23  3000 - 11/24/2017
57737 2017-11-24       P    0.01    nan     nan      -581.23  3000 - 11/24/2017
57733 2017-11-24       C  537.75    nan     nan      -531.23  3050 - 11/24/2017
57738 2017-11-24       P    0.01    nan     nan      -531.23  3050 - 11/24/2017
57727 2017-11-24       P    0.20   7.77  -25.05      -431.23  3150 - 12/08/2017
57728 2017-11-24       P    0.30  11.49  -34.45      -381.23  3200 - 12/08/2017
57734 2017-11-24       C  362.75    nan     nan      -356.23  3225 - 11/24/2017
57739 2017-11-24       P    0.01    nan     nan      -356.23  3225 - 11/24/2017
57729 2017-11-24       P    0.40  14.84  -43.17      -356.23  3225 - 12/08/2017
57826 2017-11-24       C  234.50 140.14 -124.53      -231.23  3350 - 12/22/2017
57845 2017-11-24       P    5.70 140.19 -156.23      -231.23  3350 - 12/22/2017
57827 2017-11-24       C  210.50 160.38 -138.61      -206.23  3375 - 12/22/2017
57846 2017-11-24       P    6.70 160.34 -170.27      -206.23  3375 - 12/22/2017
57828 2017-11-24       C  186.80 184.35 -154.72      -181.23  3400 - 12/22/2017
57847 2017-11-24       P    8.10 185.20 -187.99      -181.23  3400 - 12/22/2017
57829 2017-11-24       C  163.60 213.17 -174.17      -156.23  3425 - 12/22/2017
57848 2017-11-24       P    9.80 213.01 -205.82      -156.23  3425 - 12/22/2017
```

To try to make it faster, I tried the following:

```
new_d1= d1.groupby(['code','Date'], as_index=False).ffill().bfill()
```

This doesnt work as expected (as the code above works). It seems like it works as if we are only grouping by Date and not "code". Here is the output:

```
>>> new_d1
Out[59]: 
            Date      sym   Last    M1      M2         dist           code
52735 2017-11-23       C    0.10   4.72   -9.27       677.93  4250 - 12/15/2017
52736 2017-11-23       P  684.20   1.43 -106.09       677.93  4250 - 12/15/2017
53144 2017-11-23       C    0.10   4.49   -9.37       727.93  4300 - 12/15/2017
53145 2017-11-23       P  734.20   0.69 -105.02       727.93  4300 - 12/15/2017
52738 2017-11-23       P  784.20   4.29   -9.46       777.93  4350 - 12/15/2017
52737 2017-11-23       C    0.10   4.29   -9.46       777.93  4350 - 12/15/2017
53081 2017-11-23       P  834.20   4.12   -9.55       827.93  4400 - 12/15/2017
53019 2017-11-23       C    0.10   4.12   -9.55       827.93  4400 - 12/15/2017
52747 2017-11-23       C    0.10   3.96   -9.64       877.93  4450 - 12/15/2017
52748 2017-11-23       P  884.20   3.96   -9.64       877.93  4450 - 12/15/2017
52605 2017-11-23       C    0.10   3.81   -9.71       927.93  4500 - 12/15/2017
52606 2017-11-23       P  934.20   3.81   -9.71       927.93  4500 - 12/15/2017
52753 2017-11-23       C    0.10   3.68   -9.79       977.93  4550 - 12/15/2017
52754 2017-11-23       P  984.30   2.04 -109.96       977.93  4550 - 12/15/2017
53020 2017-11-23       C    0.10   3.56   -9.86      1027.93  4600 - 12/15/2017
53082 2017-11-23       P 1034.30   1.55 -108.99      1027.93  4600 - 12/15/2017
54698 2017-11-23       P 1134.30   0.53 -106.79      1127.93  4700 - 12/15/2017
54687 2017-11-23       C    0.10   3.35   -9.99      1127.93  4700 - 12/15/2017
52337 2017-11-23       C    0.10   3.17  -10.11      1227.93  4800 - 12/15/2017
52338 2017-11-23       P 1234.30   3.17  -10.11      1227.93  4800 - 12/15/2017
54699 2017-11-23       P 1334.30   3.01  -10.22      1327.93  4900 - 12/15/2017
54688 2017-11-23       C    0.10   3.01  -10.22      1327.93  4900 - 12/15/2017
52191 2017-11-23       P    0.10   0.55  -11.15     -3072.07   500 - 12/15/2017
52190 2017-11-23       C 3066.80   0.29   82.60     -3072.07   500 - 12/15/2017
52339 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.87  -10.32      1427.93  5000 - 12/15/2017
52340 2017-11-23       P 1434.40   1.26 -110.86      1427.93  5000 - 12/15/2017
54689 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.75  -10.41      1527.93  5100 - 12/15/2017
54700 2017-11-23       P 1534.40   0.45 -108.55      1527.93  5100 - 12/15/2017
52341 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.65  -10.50      1627.93  5200 - 12/15/2017
52342 2017-11-23       P 1634.40   2.65  -10.50      1627.93  5200 - 12/15/2017
52439 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.55  -10.58      1727.93  5300 - 12/15/2017
52440 2017-11-23       P 1734.50   1.72 -114.79      1727.93  5300 - 12/15/2017
52343 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.46  -10.66      1827.93  5400 - 12/15/2017
52344 2017-11-23       P 1834.50   1.08 -112.69      1827.93  5400 - 12/15/2017
54701 2017-11-23       P 1934.50   0.40 -110.30      1927.93  5500 - 12/15/2017
54690 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.38  -10.73      1927.93  5500 - 12/15/2017
52346 2017-11-23       P 2034.50   2.31  -10.80      2027.93  5600 - 12/15/2017
52345 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.31  -10.80      2027.93  5600 - 12/15/2017
54691 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.24  -10.87      2127.93  5700 - 12/15/2017
54702 2017-11-23       P 2134.60   1.52 -116.68      2127.93  5700 - 12/15/2017
52348 2017-11-23       P 2234.60   0.97 -114.51      2227.93  5800 - 12/15/2017
52347 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.18  -10.93      2227.93  5800 - 12/15/2017
54703 2017-11-23       P 2334.60   0.37 -112.06      2327.93  5900 - 12/15/2017
54692 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.13  -10.99      2327.93  5900 - 12/15/2017
52192 2017-11-23       C 2966.80   0.46   80.38     -2972.07   600 - 12/15/2017
52193 2017-11-23       P    0.10   0.61  -11.16     -2972.07   600 - 12/15/2017
52349 2017-11-23       C    0.10   2.08  -11.05      2427.93  6000 - 12/15/2017
52350 2017-11-23       P 2434.60   2.08  -11.05      2427.93  6000 - 12/15/2017
52194 2017-11-23       C 2866.70   0.67  -11.16     -2872.07   700 - 12/15/2017
52195 2017-11-23       P    0.10   0.67  -11.16     -2872.07   700 - 12/15/2017
54449 2017-11-23       C    0.10   1.71  -11.52      3427.93  7000 - 12/15/2017
54479 2017-11-23       P 3434.90   0.77 -119.84      3427.93  7000 - 12/15/2017
57740 2017-11-24       C  787.75   7.77  -25.05      -781.23  2800 - 11/24/2017
57742 2017-11-24       P    0.01   7.77  -25.05      -781.23  2800 - 11/24/2017
57741 2017-11-24       C  737.75   7.77  -25.05      -731.23  2850 - 11/24/2017
57743 2017-11-24       P    0.01   7.77  -25.05      -731.23  2850 - 11/24/2017
57730 2017-11-24       C  687.75   7.77  -25.05      -681.23  2900 - 11/24/2017
57735 2017-11-24       P    0.01   7.77  -25.05      -681.23  2900 - 11/24/2017
57731 2017-11-24       C  637.75   7.77  -25.05      -631.23  2950 - 11/24/2017
57736 2017-11-24       P    0.01   7.77  -25.05      -631.23  2950 - 11/24/2017
57732 2017-11-24       C  587.75   7.77  -25.05      -581.23  3000 - 11/24/2017
57737 2017-11-24       P    0.01   7.77  -25.05      -581.23  3000 - 11/24/2017
57733 2017-11-24       C  537.75   7.77  -25.05      -531.23  3050 - 11/24/2017
57738 2017-11-24       P    0.01   7.77  -25.05      -531.23  3050 - 11/24/2017
57727 2017-11-24       P    0.20   7.77  -25.05      -431.23  3150 - 12/08/2017
57728 2017-11-24       P    0.30  11.49  -34.45      -381.23  3200 - 12/08/2017
57734 2017-11-24       C  362.75  14.84  -43.17      -356.23  3225 - 11/24/2017
57739 2017-11-24       P    0.01  14.84  -43.17      -356.23  3225 - 11/24/2017
57729 2017-11-24       P    0.40  14.84  -43.17      -356.23  3225 - 12/08/2017
57826 2017-11-24       C  234.50 140.14 -124.53      -231.23  3350 - 12/22/2017
57845 2017-11-24       P    5.70 140.19 -156.23      -231.23  3350 - 12/22/2017
57827 2017-11-24       C  210.50 160.38 -138.61      -206.23  3375 - 12/22/2017
57846 2017-11-24       P    6.70 160.34 -170.27      -206.23  3375 - 12/22/2017
57828 2017-11-24       C  186.80 184.35 -154.72      -181.23  3400 - 12/22/2017
57847 2017-11-24       P    8.10 185.20 -187.99      -181.23  3400 - 12/22/2017
57829 2017-11-24       C  163.60 213.17 -174.17      -156.23  3425 - 12/22/2017
57848 2017-11-24       P    9.80 213.01 -205.82      -156.23  3425 - 12/22/2017
```

Is there any way to speed the code above or any insights into why the second one doesn't work.

Comment: It is work on my side ///

Comment: Hi Wen, i just updated my df to show 2 dates instead of 1. The issue I described would be clearer with this one.

Comment: I think your code should be fine , not sure what happen .

Comment: did you try running the 2 methods i posted above? they give different answers, right?

Comment: just added my outputs for the 2 parts also- they are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is happened to the second `bfill`(It will back fill nan for whole dataframe , rather than each subgroup),below will work for you

```
df.groupby(['code','Date']).apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill())
```

For example, we usually think this will return sum of sum for each group, but it will return one number .

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,3,4],'B':[2,3,4,5]})
df.groupby('A').sum().sum()
Out[958]: 
B    14
dtype: int64
```

Comment: @dayum yw~ happy coding